# How to print report in EXCEL format (XLS)

Tags: python, odoo

I'm a beginner of openerp 7. i just want to know the details regarding how to generate report in openerp 7 in `xls format`.

The formats supported in OpenERP report types are : pdf, odt, raw, sxw, etc..

Is there any direct feature that is available in OpenERP 7 regarding `printing the report in EXCEL format(XLS)`

Comment: This is not OpenERP but a library: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/OleFileIO_PL/0.22

Answer (score 1):

In openerp, by default there is no reporting modules for printing report in xls. you have to customize to create an xls report. you can use the python package `xlwt` to generate xls report. we have created a module to print the analysis report. following is the link http://zbeanztech.com/blog/advanced-printscreen-openerp-7

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing the report_xls module by [Noviat](http://www.noviat.com) that is available on [launchpad](https://code.launchpad.net/~openerp-community-reviewer/openerp-reporting-engines/7.0)

Answer (score 0):

In python library are available to export data in pdf and excel

For excel you can use:
           1)xlwt
           2)Elementtree

For pdf genration :
           1)Pypdf
           2)Reportlab 
      are available